# dimple.js scatterplot duplicating axis lables

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

Using dimple.js, I am rendering a scatter plot with the code below. This works fine, but when i hover the mouse over any point, the x and y values are shown twice, once as decimal and below that as percentage.  How can i simply keep the percentage x,y values in the hover-popup?  Also, is there a way to display additional items in the hover-popup?
Here is the fiddle demonstarting the issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/dizzy0ny/ch2187dd/52/

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600,600);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg);
myChart.setBounds(90, 35, 480, 400)
xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "x");
yAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
xAxis.showGridlines = true;
xAxis.tickFormat = '.1%'
yAxis.tickFormat = '.1%'
s1 = myChart.addSeries(["x","y","group"], dimple.plot.bubble, [xAxis, yAxis]);
s1.data = data_scatter

s2 = myChart.addSeries(["y","group"], dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
s2.data = data_ser1      

myChart.addLegend(90, 480, 330, 20, "left");
myChart.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs here: http://dimplejs.org/adhoc_viewer.html?id=adhoc_bar_custom_tooltips

You can change the default tooltip like so:

```
s1.getTooltipText = function (e) {
    return [
        "This is a custom tooltip!",
        "X value: %" + (e.aggField[0]*100).toFixed(2), 
        "Y value: %" + (e.aggField[1]*100).toFixed(2),
        "Group: " + e.aggField[2]
    ];
};
```

Check out your updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ch2187dd/55/

Also, try not to forget those semi-colons! :)

Comment: It's probably just because typically it would show you the value, and the percentage of that value. However, since the values you are providing are already percentages, it's just showing the same data twice unless you customize it with the provided code.